# Different recording results under same code and raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3, camera, video

I would like to record videos using this code:

```
RecordIntervalTime = 30*60 # 30 min
def camRecord():
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 24
    camera.rotation = 90
    camera.annotate_background = picamera.Color('black')
    camera.annotate_text = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    camera.annotate_text_size = 16
    date_string = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
    device_name = socket.gethostname()  # device (sensor) name
    print('Start recording with' + device_name + '_' + date_string)
    camera.start_recording('/home/pi/' + device_name + '_' + date_string + '.h264', quality=20,
                           bitrate=2*1000000)
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    while (dt.datetime.now() - start).seconds < RecordIntervalTime:
        camera.annotate_text = ' (' + device_name + ') ' + dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + ' '
        camera.wait_recording(1)
    camera.stop_recording()
    print('end recording')
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print('Recording start')
        camRecord()
        time.sleep(10)
```

My intention is recording the videos with 30 minutes interval until running out of battery. When I conducted an experiments with 10 sensors and the code, there are different results of the recording. For example, while one device recorded videos from 9:00 to 14:00 (not the time of running out), the other recorded that from 9:00 to 24:00 (the time of running out, I would like to make that).

Do you think that the differences from the code?